# Google developer account activation

Tags: google-developers-console

I paid Google 25 dollars to open a Google developer account which have accepted and created account for me but Google has not yet activated it,after how long should it be ready because now it's been more than 2 months and I can't publish my apps on playstore

Comment: You should ask google support directly.

Comment: The process of conducting Google support is too long and tedious and probably you won't make it.

Answer (score 0):

> After how long should it be ready

Well, I'd say something like a few days, one week at most.